# Retrieving list of referenced tables from a sql view using a query

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-view

Is there a way of easily retrieving a list of tables underlying a view.
For example, in the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW ExampleView AS
SELECT p.personId, p.surname, p.forename, p.countryCode, c.countryName
FROM persons AS p
INNER JOIN countries AS c ON p.countryCode = c.countryCode
```

The tables referenced are **persons** and **countries**

Is there a way of querying a system table, giving the view name, to get back the tables referenced?

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Could you be more specific, like what version of SQL Server? Also, you should specify the prefix when creating or referencing objects to avoid picking up false positives.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Added v of sql. What do you mean prefix? The above code has been stripped right down so it fits nicely on S.O - it's just an example

Comment: I mean like including `dbo.` in the create view and the query. This is a best practice and will make your code forward compatible.

Comment: Yes, I know, however it was left out for brevity for posting on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(N'dbo.ExampleView', N'OBJECT');
```

Comment: Thanks, modified slightly to:

SELECT distinct referenced_entity_name FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(N'dbo.ExampleView', N'OBJECT');